# Summarize across with a specific formula and missing values

Tags: r, dplyr, across

Using summarize across with a specific function when there are missing values

I want to have the standard errors (standard deviation divided by sqrt(number of observations)) for multiple columns, based on one factor, more or less like this:

I have this:

```
Species    Trait 1 Trait 2
Species 1      
Species 1      
Species 1      
Species 2
Species 2
Species 2
```

And I want this:

```
           Trait 1_se Trait 2_se
Species 1
Species 2
```

It's working ver well with this formula...

```
Data_ok %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ sd(.x)/ sqrt(length(.x)), .names = "{.col}_se")))
```

but I have missing values in the dataframe. When it's the case, the formula computation cannot be achieved and I have NA as a result. I've tried to use na.rm = TRUE in the formula, but it's not working, unfortunately. Where should I put na.rm=T ?

Thanks a lot,

Félix

Comment: `~sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(length(.x))`?

Comment: Seems ok with this example: `mtcars |> mutate(across(-gear, ~if_else(row_number() == 2, NA, .))) |>  group_by(gear) |> summarize(across(where(is.numeric), ~sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(length(.x)), .names = "{.col}_se"))`

Comment: Where did you add `na.rm=` in the formula? Do you want the errors to include the `NA` values in the denom (you can replace `length(.x)` with `length(n())`), or the non-null ones? (`/sqrt(sum(!is.na(.x)))`, though guard against `0`s)

Comment: Oh, that was easy..! Thanks a lot Jon Spring!

Comment: Update -- I think you need `~sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(length(.x[!is.na(.x)]))` to make both sides of the ratio exclude the NAs.

Comment: Indeed r2evans, I need to remove the na from the denom (which was not the case yet) And your solution (/sqrt(sum(!is.na(.x))) is actually working perfectly for this. So looks like it's solved! Thanks a lot